# Set UITableView frame height based on numberOfRows?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I create the UITableView in the Interface Builder, and in my VC `viewDidLoad` method I resize the tableView via `tableView.frame.size.height = 65*numberOfRows` but it does not change the frame of tableView. I also tried moving the code to `viewWillAppear` but it doesn't work either.

Because of some design issue I don't want to set the tableView scrollable, so I want to resize the tableView frame based on its row number.

Is there any way to resize a UITableView created in IB?

Comment: Can you elaborate on these design decisions? What happens when you run this app on a device where the screen cannot display the whole table view?

Comment: I embed the entire view in a UISrollView, so I scroll the entire view down not just the tableView. I set the content size of UISrollView to include the tableview.

Comment: you change tableView height before table is reload means 65*numberofrow set frame then [tabelaview reloadData]; method call @FongTinyik

Comment: @Dharmesh Dhorajiya So I should call `reloadData` after set the frame?

Comment: set frame after the `reloadData`.@FongTinyik

Comment: But I don't call reloadData in my code. If I should, where should this piece of code reside in ? `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad`? Thanks

Comment: tableView.scrollEnabled = false ?